# Regex: Match after first letter

Tags: regex

I have a list of words as follows:

```
cat
concatenate
matter
pattern
hat
rather
fathom
at
saturate
vat
```

I need a regular expression to match any words which are a single letter followed by the letters `'at'`.

I currently have `[A-Za-z]at` but that includes the `'cat'` and `'nat'` in `'concatenate'` and the `'rat'` in `'saturate'`.

How can I make it look for exactly one character before, and make sure that there is not more than 1 character before the 'at'. I tried using {1} but that still didn't work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use word boundary:

```
\b[A-Za-z]at\b
```

or, if you have string contains just those 3 characters, then you can use anchors:

```
^[A-Za-z]at$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^[A-Za-z]at$`
`[A-za-z]` would check for a single letter. Following `at` would look for exact match.
Using the `^` and `$` sign would force the word to start and end in the given boundaries.